# "I have been busy" past vs present

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, present-perfect, present-tense, simple-past

When someone asks me during a phone call  " where have you been " then I answer as follow : I have been busy

1-Does it necessarily means that I was busy and I am still busy or could it means that I was busy until the time of holding the phone call ?

2-can I say "I have been busy (for/since/over) the last 2 days".

Comment: For an answer to (2), yes you can say 'I have been busy for/over the last 2  days'. For (1), this might not be a technical response, but I would say that 'I have been busy' carries some implication that you are still busy. If this isn't what you intended, I'd recommend you say 'I was busy'.

Answer (score -1):

1/ It necessarily means that you were busy  until the time you answered the call or approximately until that time; you do not make the difference if the period during which you were busy stops at a time relatively near the time when you speak.

2/ You can use all three prépositions ([ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+busy+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20busy%20for%3B%2Cc0),  [ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+busy+since&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20busy%20since%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbeen%20busy%20since%3B%2Cc0), [ref.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+busy+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20busy%20over%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbeen%20busy%20over%3B%2Cc0)). However, each is use according to its own syntax. Using the locution "last two days" you can only say can "I have been busy (for/over) the last 2 days.".

- I have been bysy over the years.          <s>I have been busy for the years.</s>
- I have been bysy for years.                   <s>I have been busy over years.</s>

"Since" must be followed by the specification of a time in the past, not a period, unless this period is considered as a point in time.

- They have been working on that since the 1940's.

Therefore, you can't say "I have been busy since the last 2 days.".

You can say for instance "I have been busy since this morning." if the time when you speak is well after 12 o'clock; this is so because you can take the period of time as a point in time. If the time of speaking is still in the Morning you are mentioning, then it makes no sense to say "since this morning".

Moreover, a period specified by "**the last…**" can never be considered as a point in the past to use with "since"; this is so because  the time when you speak is more or less included in it. Of course, the following [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+busy+since+the+last&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)  is no guarantee this construction has not been used but it shows that it must be very rare; I am no native speaker, but I believe that native speakers will find it incorrect.